# For all sets A, B, and C. (A - B) - (B - C) = A - B

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Using set theory, prove or disprove that for all sets A, B, and C, (A - B) - (B - C) = A - B.

Here's what I did but I'm not sure if I'm correct, especially on line 6 (ie. Complement Law)

=(−)−(−)=−
$$=(∩)−(∩) −−−   $$
$$=(∩)∩(∩) −−−  $$
$$=(∩)∩(∩) −−−      2 $$
$$=(∩∩)∪(∩∩) −−−  $$
$$=(∩∅)∪(∩∩) −−−   1 $$
$$=∅∪(∩∩) −−−    1 $$
$$=∩∩  −−−  $$
$$=−+$$
$$=−$$
$$ ℎ,≠$$
$$∴  , ,      (−)−(−)=−$$

Comment: you should move this comment into the body of your question, it’ll make it much more accessible and easier to read

Comment: I think it might be helpful to look at it from a more intuitive perspective. What's really going on here? We have a circle that represents A, another representing B, and a third representing C. Finding A-B is like slicing out a small bit of A where they intersect. The set B-C is a piece of B, but we already sliced anything with B out of A, so (A-B)-(B-C) isn't any different than A-B.

Another more intuitive way of looking at it: which elements $x$ remain in (A-B) - (B-C)?. Well, $x$ has to be in A. Also, if $x\in B$ or $x\in B-C\subseteq B$ then it gets removed. So, $x\in A-B$.

Comment: If you start with a group of people, subtract out all the men, and then further subtract out all the men without hats, the second subtraction does nothing, and you end up with just the non-men from the original set.

Comment: Thank, guys.  Will need to digest further but am still confused.

Comment: Might be easier to element chase.  If $x\in A-B$ then $x \in A$ but $x \not \in B$.  So $x\in A-B$.  But $x \not \in B$.  So $x \not \in B-C$ (as every element of $B-C$ is in $B$).  so $x\in (A-B)-(B-C)$.  So $A-B \subseteq (A-B)-(B-C)$. But obviously $(A-B)-(B-C) \subseteq A-B$ (by definition.  Every element of $(A-B)-(B-C)$ is in $A-B$).  So we have $A-B {\subseteq\over\supseteq} (A-B)-(B-C)$ so $A-B = (A-B)-(B-C)$

Comment: Alternatively:  first prove that if $M\subset B$ then $(A-B)-M = A-B$.  Intuitively that should be obviously.  Since $A-B$ has no elements of $B$ further removal of elements of a subset of $B$ won't make any difference as they have already been removed.